# Can i trigger an ajax call based on a php conditional?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Page loads...

php loop displays tier 1 data.

click tier 1 -> ajax call to tier 2 data (html)

click tier 2 -> second ajax call to tier 3 data (html)

This all works fine.

What I want to do is make the second ajax call based on a conditional php statement in the first ajax call. If there is only 1 result for the first ajax call, then initiate the second ajax call.

pseudo code to help explain:

```
while(first_array) {
 $id = first_array['id'];
 echo '<button data="'.$id.'">first ajax call to tier 2 data</button>';
}
```

tier 2 (ajax1)

```
while(second_array) {
$id_2 = second_array['pid'];

    if ($result == 1) {

       //  trigger second ajax call to tier 3 //

    } else {
       echo '<button data="'.$id_2.'">second ajax call to tier 3 data</button>';
   }
}
```

**Is this possible?**

I understand server side php and client side javascript. And I realize the barriers or limitations there. But can I echo something in the PHP that will instigate the secondary ajax call when the *first* call is initiated?

I kind of have it working by adding a php function to the php of the first ajax call and the conditional calls the function, otherwise the function isn't used. The function just duplicates the second ajax php. I'm uncertain if replicating code like this is a good idea. I tend to not like it because edits require multiple locations to edit one item. An include didn't work.

Comment: You could possibly return an object from PHP, such as `{"triggerSecondCall": true, "data": "actual data that will get rendered"}` and decide based on that. Another option would be to count the results in PHP during the first AJAX call and act appropriately right away, if possible (without having to wait for second AJAX call).

Comment: The problem with counting rows, is the initial php page doesn't pull from the tier 2 table. And adding that factor slows page load considerably. Even if it's just to count rows based on the primary data id. This is one reason I'm building ajax for it. Initial data is maybe 900 records, tier 2 data is in the 10s of thousands, tier 3 data is in the 100s of thousands.

Comment: Php/ server Session variable to keep track of the state of tier 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I've sorted it.

Ajax Call 1 incudes a query. I modified that query to pull specific row counts as well as the other data. Based upon those counts I added a conditional which is essentially:

```
if ($theCount == 1) { 
    echo '<div class="dataholder opened">'; 
    myFunction();
    echo '</div>';
 } else { 
    echo '<div class="dataholder"></div>'; //populated by ajax call 2
 }
```

`myFunction()` is essentially the same code for the second ajax call.

This does mean I need to edit 2 locations should changes be required, but I'm not seeing a direct way around that at the moment. essentially I can just copy/paste the php from the ajax call to the function and only tweak  the concatenated output variable.